# How can I make Angular component animations follow CSS class changes, rather than static styles?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, animation

I've created a block-cursor date/time input field that uses Angular states and animations to indicate both ongoing states (like being disabled) or animated transitional states (like a red flash when an invalid keystroke has been entered). These input fields can be seen in use here: https://skyviewcafe.com/

```
export const BACKGROUND_ANIMATIONS = trigger('displayState', [
  state('error',     style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(ERROR_BACKGROUND, '#F67') })),
  state('normal',    style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(NORMAL_BACKGROUND, 'white') })),
  state('confirm',   style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(CONFIRM_BACKGROUND, '#6C6') })),
  state('warning',   style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(WARNING_BACKGROUND, '#FC6') })),
  state('view-only', style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(VIEW_ONLY_BACKGROUND, 'black') })),
  state('disabled',  style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(DISABLED_BACKGROUND, '#CCC') })),
  state('dark-error',     style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(ERROR_BACKGROUND, '#C36', true) })),
  state('dark-normal',    style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(NORMAL_BACKGROUND, '#333', true) })),
  state('dark-confirm',   style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(CONFIRM_BACKGROUND, '#292', true) })),
  state('dark-warning',   style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(WARNING_BACKGROUND, '#B80', true) })),
  state('dark-view-only', style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(VIEW_ONLY_BACKGROUND, '#0A0', true) })),
  state('dark-disabled',  style({ backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(DISABLED_BACKGROUND, '#444', true) })),
  transition('normal => error',   animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('error => normal',   animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('normal => confirm', animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('confirm => normal', animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('warning => error',  animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('error => warning',  animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-normal => dark-error',   animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-error => dark-normal',   animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-normal => dark-confirm', animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-confirm => dark-normal', animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-warning => dark-error',  animate(FLASH_DURATION)),
  transition('dark-error => dark-warning',  animate(FLASH_DURATION))
]);
```

The above animations are defined in an abstract superclass so that concrete subclasses can use them like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tbw-time-editor',
  animations: [BACKGROUND_ANIMATIONS],
  templateUrl: '../digit-sequence-editor/digit-sequence-editor.directive.html',
  styleUrls: ['../digit-sequence-editor/digit-sequence-editor.directive.scss', './time-editor.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TimeEditorComponent), multi: true },
              { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TimeEditorComponent), multi: true }]
})
export class TimeEditorComponent extends DigitSequenceEditorDirective<number> implements OnInit {
  ...
```

First of all, I'd prefer to cut the number of display states in half. I consider it a hack to have to have all of those `dark_`-prefixed states. I'd rather have these colors automatically update, as they do for DOM elements, simply by adding the `tbw-dark-mode` class to the body of my HTML document.

I'm also limited to supporting only the two pre-defined modes, light and dark. Users can customize both the light mode and the dark mode, but a third mode, or generalized "skins" would be impossible.

Timing also matters. These colors are generated once during the initialization of the application in which my components are embedded, and I see no access to an Angular API that allows these state definitions to be updated later.

The function `getBackgroundColor()` at least allows me to check once how colors have been defined at start-up, but it's not perfect (iOS Safari messes up and thinks everything is transparent), so I have to define fixed fallback values which can't be updated from a style sheet.

I did discover a disgusting hack to get some dynamic updating of colors, but it's not something I'd want to rely on! Instead of using a string for each color, I defined a dynamic color object like this:

```
class DynamicColor extends String {
  constructor(private colorKey: string) {}

  // ...

  toString(): string {
    return this.colorTable[colorKey];
  }
}
```

Even that requires some forced type coercion to `string`, and forced screen refreshing to make changes take effect.

Is there a better way? A way to use CSS classes instead of statically-defined styles? An API I haven't found yet to update the animations which are installed by the `@Component` decorator?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS variables for the colors?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

You can then just change, for example the background color from `--color-1` to `--color-2` in the state animations.

And in a separate part of your application you can change the definitions of these variables using something like this:

```
@Component({ /*…*/ })
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding("style.--color-1")
  private color1: string;

  changeColor1(value: string) {
   this.color1 = value;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Support for CSS variables is pretty good as long as you don't need to support IE: https://caniuse.com/css-variables

Comment: When I dig into the innards of the Angular code, these color assignments come down to this line of code: `element.style[camelProp] = styles[prop];`. When a color is set that way, there's no mechanism in place to interpret CSS variables. That's done at the level of style sheets. Only a concretely defined color will work in the above code.